# How can I use libraries when using router in riot.js?

Tags: riot.js

I'm developing my application with riot.js and I want to use dropzone(http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

In my code:

index.html below,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <app></app>
  <script src="dist/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.tag below,

```html
var route = require('riot-route'); require("dropzone"); require('./main/home.tag'); require('./main/contents1.tag');

<app>
  <main>
    <contents></contents>
  </main>
  <script>
    route(function(tagName) {
      tagName = tagName || 'home'
      riot.mount('contents', tagName)
    })
     route.start(true)
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.css" />
</app>
```

home.tag below,

```html
<home>
  <div class="search-box"></div>
</home>
```

Then, I add `<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>` into app.tag like this, it works right.

```html
<contents></contents>
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

but, I add it into home.tag like this,

```html
<home>
  <div class="search-box"></div>
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
</home>
```

it doesn't work. Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update DropZone when mounting the tag, using on('mount', or also you can try with on('updated',

```
<home>
  <div class="search-box"></div>
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
  <script> 
    this.on('mount', function(){
      new Dropzone(".dropzone");
    })
  </script>
</home>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I had to add one more line `var Dropzone = require("dropzone")` above `new Dropzone(".dropzone");`, but It did work!! Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. if you are happy with the solution you can mark the answer as correct.